# Ubuntu Server 18.04 — Use nmcli to (only) discover wifi networks but don’t interfere with netplan and networkd

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

Ubuntu Server 18.04 now uses netplan to manage ethernet and wifi devices.

I’d like to be able to discover wifi networks via `nmcli`, as I’d like to use [php-wifi](https://github.com/sanchescom/php-wifi) in one projects.

Is it somehow possible to set up nmcli to only discover wifi networks but not the somehow interfere with netplan and networkd?

```
$ nmcli radio wifi
enabled
```

```
$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
wlp2s0  wifi      unavailable  --
eno1    ethernet  unmanaged    --
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Comment: Have yout tried `nmcli dev wifi rescan`?

Comment: `$ nmcli dev wifi rescan` results in
`Error: Scanning not allowed while unavailable or activating.`

Comment: Are you sure wifi is working?  I use `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Wi-Fi is working. But it’s using netplan/networkd as described above. `$ nmcli device wifi list` results in `IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `NetworkManager` tools for managing your wifi, you can configure netplan to use the NetworkManager backend instead of the networkd backend for those devices:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to switch to using NetworkManager to manage the devices, you can use the lower-level `iwlist` tool for viewing available networks:

```
iwlist wlp2s0b1 scanning
```